# Python - Print only the integers of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

So, as an example, let’s say that there is only one line of code in the program, and that line of code is `n = input()`, and let’s say that the user inputted `random123`. How can I make it so when I print `n`, it only prints the integers of `n`, or 123? Note that I want this to work even if the user input is `random123random456`. If the user input IS “random123random456,” I want it to print `123456`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generator expression with a call to the `str.isdigit` method as a filter:

```
''.join(c for c in n if c.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way is to remove any non numeric character from the string with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html)

Example:

```
import re
test = "123string456"

result = re.sub('\D', '', test)
```

Here \D means any character different from 0...9
You can then replace it with empty character

Some results:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\D', '', 'random123random456')
'123456'
>>> re.sub('\D', '', 'random123')
'123'
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
test = "123string456"
output = str()
for each in test:
    try:
        n = int(each)
        output = "{}{}".format(output,n)
    except:
        pass

print(output)
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend replacing `except:` with `except ValueError:`. See [What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except).